# Events not flowing to Application Insights when using secrets.json in localhost

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-application-insights

I used this [Application Insights getting started](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started) guide for setting up my application. I'm running `VS2017 version 15.5.7` and my application is using `AspNetCore 2.0.0`.

When I F5 debug my application using IIS Express from Visual Studio, I see Application Insights events within the debugger Events window. However, the same events are not flowing to Application Insights in Azure; I've configured the `InstrumentationKey` within `secrets.json` as you can see below. I've confirmed the key is loaded into my application configuration by setting a breakpoint.

As another debugging data point, I've confirmed events do successfully flow to Application Insights when running in a Azure Web App. This test uses the exact same code. Instead of loading the `InstrumentationKey` from secrets.json, however, I've configured `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` environment variable to have the key (via `ApplicationSettings` pane of the Web App in the portal).

I'm at a loss for why my events are not flowing to Application Insights via localhost debugger, but they are when deployed to a Web App.

**Program.cs**

```
public static void Main( string[] args )
{
    BuildWebHost( args ).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost( string[] args ) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder( args )
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .Build();
```

**Startup.cs**

```
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath( hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath )
    .AddJsonFile( $"appsettings.{hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true );

if ( hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() )
{
    configurationBuilder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>( optional: true );
}

this.Configuration = configurationBuilder
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

**secrets.json**

```
{
    "ApplicationInsights": {
        "InstrumentationKey": "omitted for StackOverflow"
    }
}
```

**my.csproj**

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" Version="2.5.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
```

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:2322/",
        "sslPort": 44330
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44330/",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    },
    "FrontDoor": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44330/api/config",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:2323"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It might take a while before the arrive at the portal. AI events are buffered internally and send every x (30?) seconds. Might that be the issue?

Comment: @PeterBons, thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know they buffered and send periodically. Unfortunately, it does not help to wait longer; they never show up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. when you see appinsights events in the debugger output window, do those events say `(unconfigured)` in them?  if that is present in the output window, that would mean that the sdk is running in debug, but not finding the instrumentation key in your **`appsettings.json`** (or in code) *note that the application insights sdks don't look in usersecrets for this setting, only appsettings!*  (**edit 5/28/2020**: see OP's edit below, while this was the issue 2 years ago, if you use `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry` instead of the obsolete `UseApplicationInsights` this limitation does not apply)
2. if the events in the debugger window *do not* say `(unconfigured)`, the next step is to use something like Fiddler to watch your outbound http traffic, to make sure you're seeing outbound calls by the SDK going to dc.services.visualstudio.com, and that those outbound calls are succeeding.  (and at this step, you can verify that the instrumentation key think you are using are using is the one the sdk is using to send the events)
3. if the events are being sent, and are using the ikey you have set, the last step is to verify that the ikey you're using is the one for the resource you're looking at in the portal.  every once in a while, someone has an ikey for "dev" somewhere, and then is looking at a "prod" resource in the portal and not seeing the events they expect.
4. if you've gotten this far, with the events being sent, sent to the ikey you want, and verified the ikey is for the resource you expect it to be, then verify that there aren't any service outages or delays that might be affecting your data, which you can find at http://aka.ms/aistatus  otherwise, you should see events normally in seconds~minutes depending on where in the world you are and what region your resource is in azure, etc.

**OP edit for completeness of answer:**

Indeed, I was hitting #1 and as John hinted in the comments, I needed to let AI SDK know about my iKey in another way. Instead of using `UseApplicationInsights()` in `Program.cs`, I've switched to using `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(configuration)` within `StartUp.ConfigureServices()`. The configuration passed along has my iKey loaded from `secrets.json`.

Comment: i'm presuming you're going to hit #1 here, since your ikey is in secrets.json.  i'm not sure that the AI sdks use the secrets infrastructure, since ikey isn't normally considered a secret (since it appears in javascript on the client side, it can't really be hidden).

Comment: see https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/535 for discussion, AI doesn't look in user secrets, you'd have to add code to read from usersecrets and pass that to AI yourself, or if hosting on azure there are other ways to set the key.

Comment: Very interesting learning here, John. You are indeed correct that I'm hitting #1. Recommendation is to not place iKey in `secrets.json` sounds like.

Why is iKey not considered a secret by the way? I'd ideally like no one to know it, so they couldn't flood my AI. Is there another recommended mechanism for filtering events to an AI I should consider?

Lastly, do you have a hunch for why AI SDK is not detecting iKey from the `IConfiguration` I've built? I placed a breakpoint after building the config and confirmed the iKey was read from `secrets.json`. Where does AI SDK get the iKey from?

Comment: By the way, I was assuming the `IConfiguration` was key for AI SDK to work since the getting-started guide, mentioned in the question, pointed it out as an important step. Now that I re-read, I guess it's only if you're using the `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry` path as opposed to `UseApplicationInsights`?

Comment: ai ikeys aren't generally considered a secret since they only allow you to *write* data.  yes, someone could use your key and generate garbage, but they could do the same by just programatically hitting your site as well.  any APM like service (including Google Analytics, etc) have to have some kind of key in javascript to send data somewhere.  and since javascript, you can't hide it.  The only true way to keep it "secret" is to *only* send data from server side components where you can really hide the key.

Comment: Help me understand this part though, @JohnGardner: "note that the application insights sdks don't look in usersecrets for this setting, only appsettings!" How does it know? Doesn't `ConfigurationBuilder` mush all the configuration sources together so the app code doesn't have to worry about that kind of detail? What's going on in `ConfigurationBuilder` that makes this distinction even possible?

Comment: i believe that back in the day, appinsights sdk didn't use the configurationbuilder to get its settings? given it is more than 2 years ago, and .net core and the ai sdks have changed a LOT since then.  i think the old `UseApplicationInsights()` method before didn't have access to configuration like it does now with `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(config)` ?

Comment: if i dig 2 repos and a giant merge away, i find the method in question here, `UseApplicationInsights` was obsoleted 11 months ago: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/commit/23959caca0aebc108ea04de124248a893aa6b071, for this and many other reasons: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/919

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation, being fixed in the coming beta.
https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1882

Until then workaround is to use the AddApplicationInsights(IConfiguration) overlaod.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` version 2.15.0 this problem has been fixed.

For lower versions the overload `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration)` would read also from `secrets.json`.

> User secrets and other configuration providers
>
> If you want to store the instrumentation key in ASP.NET Core user
> secrets or retrieve it from another configuration provider, you can
> use the overload with a
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration parameter. For
> example, services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);.
>
> Starting from Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore version 2.15.0,
> calling services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry() will automatically
> read the instrumentation key from
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration of the application.
> There is no need to explicitly provide the IConfiguration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core